# An iterator that prints part of a string

Tags: python

[image]

I want to create an iterator to run and print all the parts with the numbers, how do I access them?
I marked in black what I needed the narrator to run and print

Comment: The trick with `.split(',')` applies here as well

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please [do not post code/data as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two splits, one at `-` and one at `,`

```
notes = 'sol,250-mi,250-mi,500-fa,250-re,250-re,500-do,250-re,250-mi,250-fa,250'
numbers = [temp.split(',')[1] for temp in notes.split('-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there already. After your first `split` command, `duration` is a list of strings.

Then you iterate over those strings and on each of those you call `split` again, but with `,` instead of `-`.